# No Content in my header

Tags: header-footer

I'm having a problem with getting headers in my thesis
Code is 
:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\includeonly{Chapters/Chapter1,Chapters/Chapter2,Chapters/Chapter3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\begin{document}
\title{
\huge{\textbf{Luminescent properties of semiconductor materials}}\\[1.2cm]
\Large{A thesis submitted to the University of Manchester \\ for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Facultly of Engineering and Physical Science} \\[1cm]
\Large{2015} \\
\Large{Rachel Southern-Holland} } 
\author{} 
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\newpage

\include{Chapters/Chapter1} %Introduction
\include{Chapters/Chapter2} %Literature review
\include{Chapters/Chapter3} %Methods

\end{document}
```

But I just get a line at the top of the document but no chapter name.
Anyone see where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Depending on certain class options the `\chapter` may issue header content as part of the `\rightmark` rather than `\leftmark`...

Comment: Adding  `\documentclass{book}` to make it compilable, i see headers.

Comment: You really ought not to put formatting like that into `\title`. Why don't you use the `titlepage` environment?

Comment: I'm using report document class. Still don't get any header content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed your example so it can be run and the heading code you provide does provide headings on left (even) pages, it does not have headings on odd (right) pages as you have `\rhead{}`

so page 4 has:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\includeonly{Chapters/Chapter1,Chapters/Chapter2,Chapters/Chapter3}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\begin{document}
\title{Luminescent properties of semiconductor materials}

\begin{abstract}A thesis submitted to the University of Manchester \\ for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Facultly of Engineering and Physical Science
\end{abstract}

%{\Large 2015}  %NOT \Large{2015}!!! (otherwise whole document will be large

\author{Rachel Southern-Holland}

\date{2015}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Zzzzz}
\section{bbb}
aaaa aaaa aaa \newpage bbb bbb bbb 
aaaa aaaa aaa \newpage bbb bbb bbb 

\chapter{Zzzzzzzz}
\section{bbb bb}
aaaa aaaa aaa \newpage bbb bbb bbb 
aaaa aaaa aaa \newpage bbb bbb bbb 




\end{document}
```